# Moving <body> disables me from scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, css

I just inserted the possibility to open a menubar at the left side of my webpage by moving the whole `<body>`. Appearing and disappearing works all fine. But even when the menubar is hidden it is not possible anymore to scroll down the webpage.

**HTML:**

```html
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>JFP</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp/css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/static/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body-wrapper">
        <div class="menu">
            <div class="icon-close">
                <img src="http://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/courses/ltp2/img/uber/close.png">
            </div>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="header">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-1 text-center">
                        <div class="icon-menu">
                            <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-10 text-center">
                        <li><a>!</a></li>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-1 text-center"></div>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="jumbo">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="een">
                            <img id="een" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/design.svg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                            <img id="eeneen" src="http://s.petrolicious.com/2015/vintage-friday/08-aug/paris/paris-6.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" style="display:none">
                            <div class="texteen text center" style="display:none">
                                 <h1>Lorem ipsum.</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="twee">
                            <h1>π</h1>
                            <div class="tweetwee" style="display:none">
                                 <h2>Lorem ipsum.</h2>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="drie">
                            <img id="drie" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/design.svg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                            <div class="driedrie" style="display:none">
                                 <h1>If you can see this: thanks!</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 text-center">
                        <div class="vier">
                            <img id="vier" src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/design.svg" class="img-responsive center-block">
                            <img id="viervier" src="http://thumbs.werkaandemuur.nl/6e8e65e8613d92882d69d582572a2f5b_950x600_fit.jpg" class="img-responsive center-block" style="display:none">
                            <div class="textvier text center" style="display:none">
                                 <h1>If you can see this: thanks!</h1>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="supporting">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="col">
                     <h1>If you can see this: thanks!</h1>
                     <a href="#">If you can see this: thanks!</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/develop.svg">
                     <h2>If you can see this: thanks!</h2>
                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#">If you can see this: thanks!</a>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/codecademy-content/projects/broadway/deploy.svg">
                     <h2>If you can see this: thanks!</h2>
                     <p></p>
                     <a href="#">If you can see this: thanks!</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**CSS:**

```css
html {}

body{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.menu {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    left: -185px;
    height: 200%;
    position: fixed;
    width: 185px;
}

.menu ul {
    border-top: 1px solid #636366;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.menu li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #636366;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
    line-height: 45px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-top: 3px;
}

.menu a {
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    font-size: 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.icon-close {
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.header {
}

.header i {
    font-size: 30px;
    margin-top: 15px;
}

.header a{
    color: rgb(250,250,250);
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
}

.header .col-md-10 {
    background-color: rgb(50,50,50);
    width: 85%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 40px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
}

.container-fluid {
    max-width: none;
}

jumbo {}

.jumbo .col .een {}

.jumbo .col .een img {}

.jumbo .col .een #een {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.jumbo .col .een #eeneen {
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.jumbo .col .een .texteen h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
}

.jumbo .col .twee {
    height: 350px;
    margin: 25px;
}

.jumbo .col .twee h1 {
    font-size: 160px;
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.jumbo .col h2 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.jumbo .col .drie {}

.jumbo .col .drie img {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.jumbo .col .drie h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: bottom;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    border-radius: 1500px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

.jumbo .col .vier {}

.jumbo .col .vier img {}

.jumbo .col .vier #vier {
    height: 170px;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    padding-top: 50px;
    margin-top: 60px;
}

.jumbo .col .vier #viervier {
    height: 250px;
    width: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
}

.jumbo .col .vier .textvier h1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 21px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 350px;
}

.supporting {
    padding-top: 80px;
    padding-bottom: 100px;
}

.supporting .col {
    float: left;
    width: 33%;
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 24px;
}

.supporting img {
    height: 32px;
    margin-top: 150px;
}

.supporting .col h1 {
    font-size: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 48px;
    margin-top: 190px;
}

.supporting h2 {
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 23px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    padding: 0 50px;
    margin-bottom: 60px;
}

.supporting p {
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 20px;
}

.supporting a {
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333333;
    font-weight: 600;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #333333;
    padding: 15px 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    letter-spacing: 1.1px;
}

.clearfix {
    clear: both;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #333;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 30px 0;
}

.footer p {
    font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
    text-transform: normal;
    font-size: 11px;
}

@media (max-width: 500px) {
    .main h1 {
        font-size: 50px;
        padding: 0 40px;
    }
    .supporting .col {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".icon-menu").click(function () {
        $(".menu").animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 600);
        $(".icon-menu").toggle(1600);

        $("body").animate({
            left: "185px"
        }, 600);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.icon-close').click(function () {
        $('.menu').animate({
            left: "-185px"
        }, 600);
        $(".icon-menu").toggle(600);

        $('body').animate({
            left: "0px"
        }, 600);
    });
});

var operator = '+=';
var operator1 = '+=';
var operator11 = '+=';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".een").click(function () {
        $("#een").animate({
            left: operator + '-200',
            bottom: operator + '-330',
            width: operator1 + '-85',
            height: operator1 + '-85',
            marginTop: operator11 + '-145',
            paddingTop: operator11 + '-50',
        });
        if (operator == '+=') {
            operator = '-=';
        } else {
            operator = '+=';
        }
        if (operator1 == '+=') {
            operator1 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator1 = '+=';
        }
        if (operator11 == '+=') {
            operator11 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator11 = '+=';
        }
        $("#eeneen").toggle(300);
        $(".texteen").toggle(600);
    });
});

var operator2 = '+=';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".twee").click(function () {
        $(".twee").children('h1').animate({
            top: operator2 + '-60'
        });
        if (operator2 == '+=') {
            operator2 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator2 = '+=';
        }
        $(".tweetwee").fadeToggle(600);
    });
});

var operator3 = '+=';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".drie").click(function () {
        $("#drie").animate({
            top: operator3 + '-60'
        });
        if (operator3 == '+=') {
            operator3 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator3 = '+=';
        }
        $(".driedrie").toggle(600);
    });
});


var operator4 = '+=';
var operator5 = '+=';
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".vier").click(function () {
        $("#vier").animate({
            left: operator4 + '-200',
            bottom: operator4 + '-330',
            width: operator5 + '-85',
            height: operator5 + '-85',
            marginTop: operator5 + '-145',
            paddingTop: operator5 + '-50',
        });
        if (operator4 == '+=') {
            operator4 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator4 = '+=';
        }
        if (operator5 == '+=') {
            operator5 = '-=';
        } else {
            operator5 = '+=';
        }
        $("#viervier").toggle(300);
        $(".textvier").toggle(600);
    });
});
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xwwPjQ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the style change body style as below

```
body{
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
    position: relative;
}
```

Redefined overflow property

Comment: Yes it is working! Even removing the whole `overflow` statement solves the problem. Can you tell me what the function is of this command?

Comment: I have changed the function but it is giving some problem

Comment: var bodywidth = $('body').width();
    $(".icon-menu").click(function() {
    $(".menu").animate({
    left: "0px"
    }, 600);
    $(".icon-menu").toggle(1600);

    $("body").animate({
    left: "185px",
    width: (bodywidth-185) + "px"
    }, 600);
    });

Comment: I have added the above function but it is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  overflow-x:hiiden;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
}
```

Comment: This was flagged as low quality content by SO users. Please explain your answer to avoid down votes/deletion.